# Loop a line command in bash

Tags: bash, loops

How would I loop this line to print everything jpg to a text file??

```
stat --printf="%s" *.jpg >> results.txt
```

How would you also be able to print results.txt based on a file size?? How would the code look??  The exact size of the file is 40318

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to achieve in more detail, it's hard to tell what you're trying to loop over. And also, please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I need to print filename and file size to a .txt file.  I need to figure out how to make it look in a directory.

Comment: I'm afraid it is still not clear what you want. Do you want to print out the sizes of all .jpg files?  Or only the ones that has the size 40318? Also, are you interested in jpg files only in a specific directory, or in sub-directories as well?

Comment: Assuming what you want is related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412827/bash-to-determine-file-size) I've posted an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already are printing the results for all *.jpg files. The only problem is that by using `--printf="%s"` you are changing the output format of `stat` to print only the size (without line breaks or spaces in between each item).

Try  instead:

```
stat --printf="%s\n" *.jpg >> results.txt
#  OR
stat -c "%s" *.jpg >> results.txt
```

To print the filename next to the size, try:

```
stat --printf="%n %s\n" *.jpg >> results.txt
# OR
stat -c "%n %s" *.jpg >> results.txt
```

Comment: So if I wanted to only print a file name based on size would this be correct??  $filesize=123456 stat --printf="%s $filesize \n" *.jpg >> results.txt

Comment: No. "--printf" only controls how you print the output. You cannot use it to filter output. You will need to use a different command, or use a loop and an `if` statement to filter the output of `stat`.

Comment: can you declare a variable based on the size of a file and if you knew the size could it be written before the if statement?

Comment: Yes, that is all possible. If you edit your question to include more details of what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you.

Comment: @curious please edit the details into your question, not in answers.

Comment: You edited my answer which is why it needed approval and was eventually rejected by reviewers. You should have edited the details into your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is to my understanding that you want to print the size and filename of all .jpg files into a text file. You can do this with a combination of *find*, *ls* and then format the output with *awk*:

```
    find . -name "*.jpg" | xargs ls -ahl $1 | awk '{print $5" "$9}' > results.txt
```

Please note that the script will search recursively from the directory that you specify with *find*